# What is the equivalent of Presto UNNEST function in Hive

Tags: sql, arrays, hive, presto, unnest

Presto has an `UNNEST` function to explode columns made of arrays. Is there a similar one for Hive?
See docs for `UNNEST` function of Presto [here](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/sql/select.html).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `lateral view [outer] explode`. A lateral view first applies the UDTF to each row of base table and then joins resulting output rows to the input rows to form a virtual table having the supplied table alias.

This is example from [**Presto migration from Hive** docs](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/migration/from-hive.html):

```
SELECT student, score
FROM tests
LATERAL VIEW explode(scores) t AS score;
```

And example from [**Hive Lateral View**](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+LateralView) docs:

```
SELECT * FROM exampleTable
LATERAL VIEW explode(col1) myTable1 AS myCol1
LATERAL VIEW explode(myCol1) myTable2 AS myCol2;
```

Use `OUTER` keyword to generate rows even when a `LATERAL VIEW` usually would not generate a row:

```
SELECT * FROM src LATERAL VIEW OUTER explode(array()) C AS a limit 10;
```

In this example the `array` is empty, but rows from `src` will be returned

Lateral view can be used not only with `explode()` UDTF. See the list of Hive embedded [**UDTFs**](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-Built-inTable-GeneratingFunctions%28UDTF%29) with examples. Also you can write your own UDTF and use it with `LATERAL VIEW`.