# HiveQL: Select Complex Data Structure Columns with traditional values

Tags: hive

I have the attached table structure :[image: Table structure for table account_report]
How do I select all the columns from this table as I want the output to be:
msg_src_id  ,cntry_cd       ,hldr_org_addrs ,hldr_idv_tins  ,hldr_idv_nms   ,pmts

Thanks!
Sammy

Comment: HiI have tried to use impala sql by using left outer joins and I am able to expand /extract the table as desired. But we are using SAS DI which does not have an interface with Impala as yet in our org and hence the necessity to use Hive QL.

Comment: Use lateral view + explode to select from array columns, like in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51846380/2700344