# How can I merge 2 partially overlapping strings using Apache Hive?

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I have a field which holds a short list of ids of a fixed length.
e.g. `aab:aac:ada:afg`

The field is intended to hold at most 5 ids, growing gradually. I update it by adding from a similarly constructed field that may partially overlap with my existing set, e.g. `ada:afg:fda:kfc`.

The field expans when joined to an "update" table, as in the following example.
Here, `id_list` is the aforementioned list I want to "merge", and table_update is a table with new values I want to "merge" into table1.

```
insert overwrite table table1
select 
  id,
  field1,
  field2,
  case
    when (some condition) then a.id_list
    else merge(a.id_list, b.id_list)
  end as id_list

from table1 a
left join
table_update b
on a.id = b.id;
```

I'd like to produce a combined field with the following value:
`aab:aac:ada:afg:fda`.

The challenge is that I don't know whether or how much overlap the strings have until execution, and I cannot run any external code, or create UDFs.

Any suggestions how I could approach this?

Answer (score 1):

Split to get arrays, `explode` them, select existing `union all` new, aggregate using `collect_set`, it will produce unique array, concatenate array into string using `concat_ws()`. Not tested:

```
select concat_ws(':',collect_set(id)) 
from
(
select explode(split('aab:aac:ada:afg',':')) as id  --existing
union all 
select explode(split('ada:afg:fda:kfc',':')) as id  --new
);
```

You can use `UNION` instead `UNION ALL` to get distinct values before aggregating into array. Or you can join new and existing and concatenate strings into one, then do the same:

```
select concat_ws(':',collect_set(id)) 
from
(
select explode(split(concat('aab:aac:ada:afg',':','ada:afg:fda:kfc'),':')) as id  --existing+new
);
```

Most probably you will need to use `lateral view` with `explode` in the real query. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51846380/2700344) answer about lateral view usage

Update:

```
insert overwrite table table1

select  concat_ws(':',collect_set(a.idl)) as id_list,
       id,
       field1,
       field2
from
(
select 
  id,
  field1,
  field2,
  split(
  case
    when (some condition) then a.id_list
    when b.id_list is null then a.id_list
    else concat(a.id_list,':',b.id_list)
  end,':') as id_list_array 

from table1 a
     left join table_update b on a.id = b.id
)s

LATERAL VIEW OUTER explode(id_list_array ) a AS idl
group by 
       id,
       field1,
       field2
;
```

Comment: Ah! Ok, that's a start, but I need to add a clarification to the question: the fields are in two tables, and I want to combine them for each row, not two single strings.

Comment: @Jono  you can join new and existing and concatenate strings into one, then do the same

Comment: Cool! I'll see if I can implement this and get back here.