# Hive: How to explode table with map column

Tags: java, dictionary, hive, hiveql, user-defined-functions

I have a table like this

```
+-----+------------------------------+
| id    | mapCol                     |
+-----+------------------------------+
| id1   |     {key1:val1, key2:val2} |
| id2   |     {key1:val3, key2:val4} |
+-----+------------------------------+
```

so i can easily perform a query like

`select explode(mapCol) as (key, val) from myTab where id='id1'`

and i get

```
+--------+-----+
| key    | val |
+--------+-----+
| key1   | val1|
| key2   | val2|
+--------+-----+
```

I want to generate a table like this

```
+-----+------+-----+
|id   | key  | val |
+-----+------+-----+
| id1 | key1 | val1|
| id1 | key2 | val2|
| id2 | key1 | val3|
| id2 | key2 | val4|
+-----+------------+
```

note that I want to display the `id` alongwith the exploded rows. Also, for multiple id's, the `key` may be repeated, hence I want the rows to reflect that. Basically, `id` + `key` should be unique.

How would i write a query for this? I tried

`select explode(mapCol) as (key, val), id from myTab`

but i got

`FAILED: SemanticException 1:66 Only a single expression in the SELECT clause is supported with UDTF's`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [**lateral view**](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+LateralView#LanguageManualLateralView-LateralViewSyntax):

```
with MyTable as -------use your table instead of this subquery
(select id, str_to_map(mapStr) mapCol
from
(
select stack(2,
'id1','key1:val1,key2:val2',
'id2','key1:val3,key2:val4'
) as (id, mapStr))s
) -------use your table instead of this subquery

select t.id, s.key, s.val
  from MyTable t
       lateral view outer explode(mapCol) s  as key, val;
```

Result:

```
OK
id1     key1    val1
id1     key2    val2
id2     key1    val3
id2     key2    val4
Time taken: 0.072 seconds, Fetched: 4 row(s)
```

Use your table instead of `MyTable` subquery.

Read also this answer about lateral view: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51846380/2700344.

Comment: Thank you, this answer saved my butt today.  Note that if the column is already typed as a map there is no need for the str_to_map step.