# How to convert map to column in hive?

Tags: sql, dictionary, hive

Suppose we have

```
columnsA        columnsB
   1           {'A':22,'B':11}
   2           {'A':13,'C':24}
```

How to convert it to

```
columnsA   A   B   C
   1       22  11  NA
   2       13  NA  24
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [Map[key] operator](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-OperatorsonComplexTypes)

```
select m['A'] A,  
       m['B'] B, 
       m['C'] C 
  from (select str_to_map("A:22,B:11") m) s;
```

Returns:

```
A       B       C
22      11      NULL
```

If you need 'NA' instead of NULL, use NVL() function:

```
NVL(m['A'],'NA') as A
```

Comment: thank you so much! And there are more than 200 discrete values in columnB. Is there any other way?

Comment: @takashi the other way can be using `lateral view outer explode(mapCol) s  as key, val;` like in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54960324/2700344 But after that you additionally need to transpose (key, val) to the columns based on keys, this can be done using conditional aggregation. Using map[key] would be much simpler and efficient