# Can we create several entries from one line?

Tags: hive, amazon-athena, hive-serde, regexserde, presto

My logs look like this:
`client_id;event_1;event_2;event3`

And i would like to get an SQL Table like this:

```
 client_id |   event
 ---------------------
    ...    |  event_1
    ...    |  event_2
    ...    |  event_3
```

I am new to Hive, it seems to me that one log line always provides one entry in the resulting SQL table.
I tried the following (unsuccessful):

```sql
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tablename (
         client_id String,
         `event` String
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.RegexSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
         "input.regex" = "^([^\;]+);.*([^\;]+).*$" )
LOCATION 's3://myBucket/prefix/';
```

It takes only the first event and ignore the others...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to generate rows using SerDe in table DDL. It's possible to do the same in Hive.

(1) Read all user events as a single column:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tablename (
         client_id String,
         events    String
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.RegexSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
 "input.regex" = "^([^\\;]+)\\;(.*)$" )
LOCATION 's3://myBucket/prefix/';
```

Check, it should read two columns, user_id and all events concatenated:

`'client_id'` and `'event_1;event_2;event3'`

(2) Split events and explode to generate rows:

```
 select t.user_id, e.event
   from tablename t
        lateral view outer explode(split(t.events,'\\;')) e as event;
```

Read also about [Lateral View](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51846380/2700344).

In Athena use [UNNEST with CROSS JOIN](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/flattening-arrays.html):

```
select t.user_id, e.event
       from tablename t
       CROSS JOIN UNNEST(SPLIT(t.events,';')) AS e (event)
```

Comment: What a disappointment to be limited like that! It seems to be a great solution, unfortunately I am using AWS Athena which does not support this type of query (getting `Queries of this type are not supported [...]`). You answered the question though, I am just waiting any other contribution before accepting it :)

Comment: @Cinn Use UNNEST instead of Lateral view in Athena: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/flattening-arrays.html

Comment: Thank you so much, it works with `UNNEST`. You were very helpful, i am just a little disappointed that the split is done by the request and not directly in the table...