# Hive Unexpected DataOperationType: UNSET

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-storm, unset

Trying to persist hive table from storm-hive client, Getting following logs in HiveMetastoreServer logs.

```
020-02-26 23:20:27,748 ERROR org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer: [pool-8-thread-178]: Error occurred during processing of message.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unexpected **DataOperationType: UNSET** agentInfo=Unknown txnid:1641
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.txn.TxnHandler.enqueueLockWithRetry(TxnHandler.java:906) ~[hive-exec-2.1.1-cdh6.3.2.jar:2.1.1-cdh6.3.2]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.txn.TxnHandler.lock(TxnHandler.java:781) ~[hive-exec-2.1.1-cdh6.3.2.jar:2.1.1-cdh6.3.2]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have downgraded storm-hive client to 1.2.3 from 2.1.0. And also excluded  hive dependency jars from storm-hive 1.2.3 and added hive client version 2.1.1 to match my cloudera environment.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `explode` instead of `unnest`! check this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51846380/9185215